# System:Uint32^ in C++/CLI compiles to VaueType in C#?

Tags: c#, c++-cli, managed

In a C++/CLI class library I have the following function:

```
static System::UInt32^ Fn()
{
    return gcnew System::UInt32(0);
}
```

When I use the class library in a C# the System::Uint32 is a System::ValueType and the compiler error:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.ValueType' to 'uint'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Why is it that when I'm defiing a System::UInt32 in C++/CLI I get a ValueType in C#?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show how you use the function in C#?

Comment: `System::UInt32` is not a reference type, so I would ditch the `^` and the `gcnew`.

Comment: C# doesn't support strongly-typed boxed values, it displays them all as `ValueType`.

Comment: I'm surprised it doesn't show up as `object`, the only boxed type C# supports. It's easy to unbox from `object`, but how does one unbox from `ValueType`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UInt32` is a value type (`struct` in C#), not a reference type. Therefore, it does not need the `^` handle.

Switch that method to the following, and it'll appear normally in C#.

```
static System::UInt32 Fn()
{
    return 0;
}
```

If you convert the rest of your code to remove the `^` from the value types, you'll find that your C++/CLI code looks more natural, and you'll have less issues interfacing with the .Net Library.