# How to call C++/Cli function with ValueType argument from C#

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I am trying to call C++ function from C#.

Here is the C++ function definition,

```
StartRecording(DateTime^% startTimestamp, String^ recPath)
```

I want to call this from C#. The definition in C# shows,

```
StartRecording(ref ValueType startTimestamp, string recPath);
```

How can I call this function. Calling like,

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
StartRecording(ref now, "Path to file");
```

is not compiling, Error is,

```
Error   CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ref System.DateTime' to 'ref System.ValueType'
```

Comment: Compile as dll. import your dll to C# project.

Comment: @Arphile that part is done. Can not call the function. I updated the question.

Comment: this is C++/CLI actually

Comment: Does this answer your question? [System:Uint32^ in C++/CLI compiles to VaueType in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25726248/systemuint32-in-c-cli-compiles-to-vauetype-in-c)

Comment: @Aybe not really. I can not update the c++ part. DateTime in c# is a struct. Why does the compiler complain?

Comment: is StartRecording(ref DateTime startTimestamp, string recPath); doesn't work on your code?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up calling the function as follows,

```
ValueType now = DateTime.Now;
StartRecording(ref now, "Path to file");
```

assigning DateTime object to ValueType resolved the problem.